# ThreeJS exportGLTF(scene) | GLB textures broken after export | Collada

Tags: three.js, gltf

I am trying to export a collada scene with threejs using GLTFexporter from the browser, the scene renders perfectly with threejs in collada format but when I try to export a GLB file with GLTFExporter the textures look messed up and I think some maybe even missing.

I am working with a test file from the examples folder...

elf.dae and textures:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/38bf5f47a8c01a1d12d16a41b4097dc9ee31daad/examples/models/collada/elf

```
gltfExporter.parse(
    input,
    function ( result ) {

        if ( result instanceof ArrayBuffer ) {

            saveArrayBuffer( result, 'scene.glb' );

        } else {

            const output = JSON.stringify( result, null, 2 );
            console.log( output );
            saveString( output, 'scene.gltf' );

        }

    },
    function ( error ) {

        console.log( 'An error happened during parsing', error );

    },
    options
);
```

My application creates blobs for each file and texture in localStorage by name and then when it asks for the file URLModifier first checks if file exists in localStorage object and then redirects if file exists to the blobs URL.

Everything appears to work fine until I open the GLB file and view the export... You can see here that the file is rendered correctly in collada format...

[image: Collada threejs scene prior to export]

But if I open the exported file in model-viewer this is the result...

[image: Exported GLB with GLTFExporter]

Where am I going wrong? I think maybe I am not setting the correct inputs on gltfExporter, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inverting the texture in the y-axis? I think this is set to true by default, but GLTF needs it to be false.

`texture.flipY = false;`

https://threejs.org/docs/?q=texture#api/en/textures/Texture.flipY

Comment: I am loading the exported files in model-viewer due to the level of automation it provides, I think you maybe be onto something though, how would I do this prior to exportation? I am thinking maybe I could just modify all `<texture>` tags and add the attribute `flipY="false"` into the XML file, what do you think?

Comment: So I modified each `<texture>` tag in the file adding `flipY="false"` attribute to each of 4 texture tags like `<texture texture="ce_jpg-sampler" texcoord="UVMap" flipY="false"/>` and saved the result as `elf2.dae` before writing a function to modify the object and ran the export again the results prior to exportation and after in GLB format are exactly the same.